# Git hooks how to make sure you have latest commits before creating new branch?

Tags: git, githooks

We frequently have this issue:
https://medium.com/devops-with-valentine/gitlab-merge-blocked-fast-forward-merge-is-not-possible-7f86bf79e58b

And it seems the culprit, may be due to sometimes after doing a work in feature branch merging into `master`, the next feature is branched off master locally, without first ensuring to fetch the merged commits from origin.

And then, a week or so later, there's the problem mentioned above.

I'd like to avoid this, by adding a hook - whenever you do `git checkout -b` or `git branch`, a script would run, to pull the current branch off `origin` - thus ensuring that a developer's local head for the source branch, is indeed the latest at the time of creating the feature branch.

I was searching and reviewing the various hooks, none seem to be suitable.

I believe on another repo where we do `feature`->`development`->`master` branches, we encounter similar issues as well.

Comment: There is no hook that runs when you create a new branch.

Comment: But even then, somebody else could merge before the branch is finished → again, a fast-forward is not possible. It does not matter when the branch was created …